# Add space at the beginning of the page

Tags: spacing

I need a command (and a package) that add empty space at the beginning of the page.
Something like vspace{} or vspace*{}

Comment: begining of which page? if it is the first page just use `\vspace*{2cm}` if it is every page then it is not clear what you mean, perhaps you just want to increase `\topmargin` ?

Comment: Something like `\vphantom{Foo}`?

Comment: I want to add space before object if this object is at the begging of the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `\vspace` and `\vspace*` can be used:

```
\vspace{-50mm}
\vspace*{50mm}
Object
```

At the begin of a new page, the first `\vspace{...}` is automatically removed and the second `\vspace*{...}` stays. In the middle of the page, the spaces sum up to zero.